# Is there a ready made logging server compatible with log4cplus?

Tags: server, logging

Looking at the list of packages in Ubuntu, I could not find a package that could be used with log4cplus that would be a logging server.

My idea would be to be able to send logs through a server so that way it would end up in a file which can be made secure if necessary:

```
-rw-------  logger  logger     my-secret.log
-rw-r--r--  logger  logger     public.log
```

The my-secret.log could not be written by other applications, hence the need for a server. I'm wondering whether such a server already exists to avoid having to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

log4cplus source does have the `SocketAppender` which can send stuff towards `loggingserver`. However `SocketAppender` does not send all of the information that each even contain and I would recommend against using it.

Alternatively, there is the `SysLogAppender` which I would recommend. Earlier version can do remote logging only using UDP, later versions can do also syslog over TCP.

Comment: But I do not see a `loggingserver` service. So I suppose I have to build my own? I use the `SysLogAppender` for security data at this time. But was hoping I could put that in my own log file instead of filling up syslog, unless I could create a file specific to my environment and still use the `SysLogAppender`?

Comment: The `loggingserver` executable might not be distributed by Ubuntu. I do not know. As for syslog, modern syslog daemon implementations (like syslog-ng) can do filtering and you should be able to direct your logging into some other file than `messages.log`.